# How to get Thick and Black contour line in 2d list contour plot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make contour plot of a 20*20 matrix using the function ListContourPlot.

I want the contour curves to be thick and black at the same time.

So I tried

```
ContourStyle -> [Black, Thick]
```

and

```
BaseStyle -> Thick, ContourStyle -> Thick
```

and many other ways.

However, all of them give me Thick and Gray curves.

Like this

[image]

How can I make the contour curves as black as the frame lines?

Here is my data

[data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwURfSzHDI4FAvkbfJyXfRRQdqIV4RpX/view?usp=sharing)

Here is how I read in the data:

```
data = ReadList[".../2Dshape4t30.txt", Number, RecordLists -> True];
```

Here is the my code for plotting

```
ListContourPlot[data2d, Contours -> {0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.01, 0.001}, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 3, ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourLabels -> All, ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick], 
 Axes -> False , FrameStyle -> Thick, FrameTicks -> None]
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example in your question so we can test any solutions.  It looks like you are using square brackets instead of the required curly braces.  But the solution may  require more than simply changing the brackets.

Comment: `PlotTheme->"Monochrome"` ?

Comment: @LouisB Thank you for your comment! I have edited my question and added a concrete example.

Comment: @yarchik still gray..

Comment: Then you need to add `Opacity[1]` to the `ContourStyle`. It is black but partially transparent by default.

Comment: try `ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]` or `ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1],Black, Thick]`?

Comment: @yarchik That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[Sin[i  + j] Cos[i j], {i, -3, 3, 0.1}, {j, -3, 3, 0.1}];

ListContourPlot[data,
 Contours -> {0.05, -.75, .5, .95}, 
 Axes -> False , FrameStyle -> Thick, FrameTicks -> None, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ContourShading -> None, 
 ContourLabels -> All, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]]
```

[image]

You can

1. add the option `PlotTheme -> None` or
2. change the option `ContourStyle` to `ContourStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1, Black], Thick]`

to get

[image]